# Deriving average productivity from a CES production function

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, mathematical-economics

Following the work of *Raurich et al. (2012)* I got stuck trying to derive the average productivity starting from the following CES production function:

$$Y=A\left [ \alpha K^{\frac{\sigma -1}{\sigma }}+(1-\alpha)(AL)^{\frac{\sigma -1}{\sigma }} \right ]^{\frac{\sigma}{\sigma-1 }}$$

The result they get is: 
$$\left (\frac{Y}{AL}  \right )^{\frac{1-\sigma }{\sigma }}=\frac{1}{\alpha \left ( \frac{K}{AL} \right )^{\frac{\sigma-1 }{\sigma }}+(1-\alpha )}$$

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: I checked just to be sure. But actually the exponent of the LHS  is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Solution]

This is the solution to your difficulty. By the way, which text are you following?

Comment: I think OP's confusion is over why average productivity is defined in this manner. To me, average labor productivity (in efficiency units) would just be $\frac{Y}{AL}$. The paper in question is [here](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/55055/1/684015625.pdf) (see page 6 of the paper). Maybe it's just a language issue -- it is a working paper.

Comment: Yes, I'm also trying to understand this. Anyway, it is not a working paper, it has been published on Journal of Macroeconomics (Volume 34, Issue 1, March 2012, Pages 181-198).

Comment: I think this is a language issue. I see no relevance in raising average productivity to a function of elasticity of substitution and then calling it average productivity. If you find an answer, please do let me know.

Comment: Agreed that this is likely just semantics. The language preceding the expression given for average productivity is indicative to me.